# How do you play sound in C#?

Tags: c#

I've tried this but I'm interested in playing sound from where my program starts. Such I have the .wav file inside of the project folder.

```
   SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"/yay.wav");
    simpleSound.Play();
```

Thank you

Comment: One key to the right (or one fret up) from C

Comment: I think it would make more sense if you did @"\yay.wav" instead of @"/yay.wav" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Such I have the .wav file inside of the project folder.

This is probably your problem.

When you compile your application, it doesn't end up straight in the project folder - it ends up in a subdirectory (either `/Debug/bin` or `/Release/bin`). Put the wav file there instead of in the project directory and see how that works.

Comment: Another option would be to include the .wav file as a resource.

Answer (score 1):

Before you have to play sound, you must be familiar with PlaySound() Win32 API function.

```
private SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();

/// Button click event handler.
private void AsyncBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Set .wav file as TextBox.Text.
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        // Add LoadCompleted event handler.
        player.LoadCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(LoadCompleted);

        // Set location of the .wav file.
        player.SoundLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        // Load asynchronously.
        player.LoadAsync();
    }
}

/// LoadCompleted event handler.
private void LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    player.Play();
}
```