# .NET SoundPlayer QUestion

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I was hoping the code below would play the Fireball.wav file located in the same directory as the .exe.

```
 SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"Fireball.wav");
 simpleSound.Play();
```

I believe I'm setting up the wrong filepath.

Comment: Yup, you didn't actually use a path.  OpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory tends to be relevant.

Comment: -1 How is this question different from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433834  or even this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405477 ??? Are we supposed to keep guessing until we figure out which folder your Fireball.wav is in? Or are you trying to do this in a web app and not asking quite right?

Comment: also, this is a .NET SoundPlayer issue, not a C# SoundPlayer issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
              Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) 
             ,"Fireball.wav");
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(path);
simpleSound.Play();
```

Comment: This is OK but assumes that the file is local to the app. Please check my snarky comment to the OP and the links. Makes me wonder if the OP is confused between relative folders in the web world and paths in desktop apps?

Answer (score 0):

Using relative paths without a specified base path(i.e. relative to the current directory) is usually a bad idea.
The one common exception I can thing of is relative paths passed as a command line parameter into an application.

In particular the current directory is not identical to the application directory. It can be any directory on startup, and common dialogs(depending on their flags) can change it. Additionally it is a per process and not per thread variable, so another thread might change it at any time.

So I highly recommend creating an absolute path from your relative path before accessing it(See Dog Ears's post for how to do that)