# C# String Filepath Question

Tags: c#

I am trying to set a filepath for a `SoundPlayer` object

If I have a sounds folder in my main project folder. How do I go about sending

```
Soundplayer test = new Soundplayer("Sounds/Fireball.wav");
```

Comment: eh... say WHAT ? what is Soundplayer, what isn't working, what is happening and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where the file is relative to your main project is not important.  What's important is where will the sound file be relative to your application at deployment / debug time.  If it will have the same relative path as that of the main .exe path then you can use the following.

```
var root = typeof(Program).Assembly.Location;
var soundPath = Path.Combine(root, @"sounds\Fireball.wav");
var test = new SoundPlayer(soundPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the path as `@"Sounds\Fireball.wav"`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running out of Visual Studio, the current working directory will be `bin\Debug`, so the file in question would need to be in `bin\Debug\Sounds\Fireball.wav`.

Also, as others have mentioned, you should use backslash `\` rather than forwardslash `/`